# How to get original exception from CompletableFuture.join()?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, java-8, completable-future

Is there any way I can get original exception that's thrown when a task execution fails with an exception ? Looks like CompletableFuture.join always throws CompletionException in case of failures.

Our original exception contains additional attributes(member variables) which have to be used in handling the exceptions in a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()):

> To better conform with the use of common functional forms, if a computation involved in the completion of this CompletableFuture threw an exception, this method throws an (unchecked) CompletionException **with the underlying exception as its cause**.

In other words,

```
Exception original = completableException.getCause();
```

Comment: If the thrown exception wasn't itself a `CompletionException`, so the cause may be `null`.